# Angular Testing: How can i call expectations after a function got executetd

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, karma-jasmine

I am currently unit testing my application in angular and got the problem that I need to use a http call on a local file. Therefore the expects of the test got called before and after the http call so it crashes. How can I fix that problem?

I am currently trying to call the expects inside the .subscribe of the http call:

```
fit('should get local file and work with it', (done: DoneFn) => {
        let file: File;

        var blob: Blob;

        httpMockService.get('/assets/testFiles/testImage.png', { 
                      responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      
    blob = resp
    file = new File([blob], 'logo.png', 
                     { type: 'image/png', lastModified: Date.now() });

    component.submitFile(file); <- get called seecond

    expect(component.canBeProgressed).toEqual(true); <- get called first
    expect(component.submited).toEqual(false);

    done();

});
```

The problem is that the expected values are wrong, because component.submitFile got called after the expects. I tried it with a spy, but that doesn't work. Can anybody help me out?

Edit: In the submitFile() method is a FileReader included which loads the image and work with its pixels. I think that causes the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60438097/2358409

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get a file from assets to test. You can very well mock a file in your tests.

```
    fit('should get local file and work with it', () => {
          let blob = new Blob([""], { type: 'image/png' });
          blob["lastModifiedDate"] = Date.now()
          blob["name"] = "test.png";

          let mockFile = <File>blob;
   
         component.submitFile(mockFile);
    
         expect(component.canBeProgressed).toEqual(true); 
         expect(component.submited).toEqual(false);
    
    
    });
```

Comment: That is part the Problem. I need to use a file from my assets to test if the application can work with it properly. Thank you anyway for the answer.

Comment: ok, if that's the case, let me know if  submitFile method making any api call? If that's the case you will need to mock that too.

Comment: No, it does not make any api call.

Comment: But it use a filereader, wich i think cause that the function is async